# php DB returned array issue

Tags: php, database

I am trying to combine 2 db results together to have an array like the following:

```
array(
    0=>array( 
      'name'=>'John',
      'title'=>'manager',
      'email'=>'test',
      'permission'=>'1',
      'depart'=>'human resource'
      ),
    1=>array(
      'name'=>'Ted',
      'title'=>'employee',
      'email'=>'test2',
      'permission'=>'2',
      'depart'=>'human resource'
   )
)
```

The first 3 elements are from 1 returned DB result and the last two elements are from another DB results.

```
     $firstResults = DBCall::call(getName);  //get name,title,email or John and Ted as an array
     $secondResults = DBCall::call(getPermission);  //get permission and depart as an array

     //I then use array merge
     $userResults=array_merge($firstResults ,$secondResults);

     //but it will become

array(
    0=>array( 
      'name'=>'John',
      'title'=>'manager',
      'email'=>'test'

      ),
    1=>array(
      'name'=>'Ted',
      'title'=>'employee',
      'email'=>'test2'

   ),
    2=>array(
      'permission'=>'1',
      'depart'=>'human resource'
   ),
    3=>array(
      'permission'=>'2',
      'depart'=>'human resource'   
   )
)
```

Are there anyways to archieve the outcome I need? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe you can get the combined results from your SQL statement instead.

Comment: I think the most appropriate approach is to create a new DBCall::call(getNamePermission) that will use a new query.

Comment: unfortunately, I won't be able to change the db call. I have to use the current db results.

Comment: I think the only way is to actually define a new array. I had some problems with that some time ago and the only way to fixit was creating a new array using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to test out OK. http://www.laprbass.com/RAY_temp_flyingcat.php

```
<?php // RAY_temp_flyingcat.php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "<pre>";

// SIMULATE DB RESULTS SETS
$getname = array(
    0=>array(
      'name'=>'John',
      'title'=>'manager',
      'email'=>'test',
      ),
    1=>array(
      'name'=>'Ted',
      'title'=>'employee',
      'email'=>'test2',
   )
)
;

$getperm = array(
    0=>array(
      'permission'=>'1',
      'depart'=>'human resource'
      ),
    1=>array(
      'permission'=>'2',
      'depart'=>'human resource'
   )
)
;

// MERGE THE ARRAYS SENSIBLY
foreach ($getname as $key => $arr)
{
    $getboth[$key] = array_merge($getname[$key], $getperm[$key]);
}

// SHOW THE WORK PRODUCT
print_r($getname);
print_r($getperm);
print_r($getboth);
```

Best regards, ~Ray